# Passing class reference to a void function gives error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a reference of a class through a `void` function, but it throws an error.

Here is the code (it has to be a `void` function and not return anything).  If I change the function to return `int` or `string` it works fine but I don't want to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class car
{
 public:

   car()
   : wheels(4)
   {
   }

   int wheels;
 };

 void getwheels(  car& i_car )
 {
   //do something here
 }

 int main()
 {
   car mycar;

   mycar.wheels = 6;

   cout << getwheels( mycar )<< endl;
}
```

The `void` is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`getwheels` returns `void`, but you're printing it out as if it has a return value. If a function returns nothing, you can't print the result of calling it.

To solve, just call the function without printing:

```
getwheels( my_car );
```

Or if what you meant to do was print out the `wheels` value, print the value inside the function:

```
void getwheels(car& i_car)
{
    cout << i_car.wheels << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to return **wheels** from getwheels instead of **void**

```
int getwheels(const car& i_car)
{
  return i_car.wheels;
}
```

Or pass **std::ostream** into getwheels:

```
std::ostream& getwheels(std::ostream& out, const car& i_car)
{
  //do something here
  out << i_car.wheels << std::endl;;
  return out;
}

int main()
{
  car mycar;

  mycar.wheels = 6;

  getwheels(std::cout, mycar);
}
```